# Unresolved reference by Android Studio 2020.3.1

Tags: android-studio

I've used the Fullscreen Activity to create a project in Android Studio 2020.3.1. On buld of the app, I get "Unresolved reference: LastChange". The 3 lines pointed to (in FullscreenActivity.kt) are:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            LastChange.setText("Landscape")}
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            LastChange.setText("Portrait")}
        else {
            LastChange.setText("Unrecognized")}
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }
```

The TextView (in activity_xml) is coded as:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/LastChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/LastChangeText"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
```

LastChangeText (in strings.xml) is defined as:

```
<string name="LastChangeText">N/A</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your textView has "LastChange" id, that's not the way you call it from activity.

At "onCreate" method, after super.onCreate(), you'll need:

```
setContentView(R.layout.<YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME>);

val lastChangeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastChange);
```

And, after that, you can call methods on "lastChangeTextView".

```
lastChangeTextView.setText("Landscape")
```

Strongly recommend taking a look at Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira Thanks for your reply. There seems to be no facility to mark code when making a Comment. 
When I tried the above and it gave a problem on TextView in:
val lastChangeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LastChange);
I've tried val lastChangeTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.LastChange);
without success using the example of val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
in the documentation link you gave.